# c# Adding a button to column in gridview for deleting and updating

Tags: c#, gridview

Another question. First i would like to tell that all the threads here have parameterized code which i dont understand yet. so please give me simple example.

I have a **gridview** named **gridViewDatabase** in my **C# windows Application form** where i have some columns like (FirstName, LastName and so on but in the end i have two extra blank columns named **DELETE** and **EDIT**). In these last two columns i want to place two buttons in each column for **DELETING** the respective row and for **EDITING** the respective row.

I hope i made myself clear. Please help me.

Showing an image of my running program here.

[image: No Description required]

Comment: I am wondering how did you use GridView (asp.net) in C# win forms app!

Comment: Yes you made yourself clear but not readers. It is not clear what you have tried and where you have got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

In windows form called DataGridView right click on grid view -> Edit Columns -> change column type to DataGridViewButtonColumn